# Command bar hide action labels when too small

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

### Expected behavior

[image: Expected behavior]

This is what I'm trying to achieve with the [CommandBar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/commandbar).

When there's not enough space for the items label I want to hide the labels and not go in the overflow menu. When I resize the CommandBar I want the labels to reappear if there's enough space.

I'm able to hide the labels using the `iconOnly` props and the `onReduceData` callback.

Then I tried to use the `onGrowData` to restore the `iconOnly` when the commandBar is resized, but since there's no items in the overflow, the callback is never called.

### Current behavior

[image]

### Here is the simplify code:

```
<CommandBar
className='CommandBar'
items={[{
    iconProps: { iconName: 'Previous' },
    key: 'FindPrevious',
    onClick: () => { this.findPrevious() },
    text: 'Find Previous',
},
{
    iconProps: { iconName: 'Next' },
    key: 'FindNext',
    onClick: () => { this.findNext() },
    text: 'Find Next',
}]}
farItems={[{
    iconProps: { iconName: 'Search' },
    key: 'FindAll',
    onClick: this.findAll,
    text: 'Find All',
}]}

onReduceData={this.onReduceData}
/>

private onReduceData = (data: ICommandBarData): any => {
    data.primaryItems[0].iconOnly = true;
    data.primaryItems[1].iconOnly = true;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: onGrow is never called if there aren't items in the overflow? That's definitely a bug if true! Can you get this into a codepen (aka.ms/fabricpen) and submit and issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/